# How to use Mpdf library with PHPword. How can I generate .docx file to .pdf file

Tags: php, laravel, mpdf, doc, phpword

I have a problem. When I try to generate the word.docx file to pdfFile.pdf file on Laravel (PHP), using the library **[mPDF](https://github.com/mccarlosen/laravel-mpdf)** I got this error:

> PDF rendering library or library path has not been defined.

I can't found the solution. Help me please. Thank you in advance.

**My code in PHP controller file:**

```php
public function wordToPdf(){
    $domPdfPath = base_path('vendor/mpdf/mpdf');
    \PhpOffice\PhpWord\Settings::setPdfRendererPath($domPdfPath);
    \PhpOffice\PhpWord\Settings::setPdfRendererName('mPDF');
    
    //Load word file
    $Content = \PhpOffice\PhpWord\IOFactory::load(public_path( '/uploads/word/no12.docx'));
    
    //Save it into PDF
    $PDFWriter = \PhpOffice\PhpWord\IOFactory::createWriter($Content,'PDF');
    $PDFWriter->save(public_path( '/uploads/word/result3.pdf'));
    return $PDFWriter;
}
```

Help me please if anyone know it..?

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue but with different library, It was because, the Laravel could not find the base path of your PDF rendering library and it is pretty clear in your error.

All you have to do is define a path to your domPDF. A better approach would be to define a constant and then access it. Here's how you do it:

1. Create a file in your `config` folder by any name you want, `constants.php` would be a good practice since you're defining constants for your app.
2. Define a constant in that file `'your_var_name' => realpath(__DIR__),`.
3. Run these commands in your cmd: `php artisan config:cache` and `php artisan cache:clear` to clear and cache the latest configs.
4. Now in your controller setup the following settings:

**Code**:

```
// access your constant using laravel's helper config();
$domPdfPath = realpath(config('constant.your_var_name').'/../vendor/dompdf/dompdf');

Settings::setPdfRendererPath($domPdfPath);

Settings::setPdfRendererName('DomPDF');
```

Comment: Thank You for your Answer. on DOMPDF this is work fine, but on mPDF return this error. Can I use this method with mPDF??

Comment: You're welcome and it never hurts to try. :)
You have to understand what the error is trying to tell you, the laravel is unable to find the path of the pdf rendering library to generate a pdf. You can try it with mPDF. I can't tell you for sure that it will work, because I've never used that library.

Comment: I understand:)). Thank you for your answers. Good Luck.

Comment: No problem! Good luck and happy coding! :)